# .NET MAUI Android WebView JavaScriptの有効について

Tags: c#, android, .net

.NET MAUIのWebViewコントロールなのですがこいつはJavaScriptのメソッドを使用することが簡単にできるコントロールでこれを使用してアプリを作っています
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview

WindowsではこのJavaScriptがWebView上で動くことを確認できたのですがAndroidでは使えませんでした
色々原因を調べたところAndroid版のWebViewはJavaScriptを扱える機能はついているもののデフォルトでは無効となっていてWebtSettings.setJavaScriptEnabledでTrueにしないとダメらしいです
https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#java

このsetJavaScriptEnabledを.NET MAUIに実装させるにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: この辺が参考になるかも。[JS/.NET interact on MAUI...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73217992/9014308), [Android上の WebView...](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/maui/android/platform-specifics/webview-mixed-content) Xamarinだとこれら。[Xamarin Android...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50911464/9014308), [WebView...](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview) あるいは実現済み？[Pending code to port from Renderers to Handlers #4808](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4808), [Android MauiWebView Layout issue #9517](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9517)

Comment: Xamarinのやつ…こんな簡単だったなんて…ありがとうございます！